# Caché de git recuerda código viejo

Tags: git, cache, ember.js

Tengo un problema extraño. Estamos trabajando con `Ember` usando `Git` para el control de versiones ya hace un tiempo, pero en este proyecto nuevo, y por primera vez, me ha surgido un problema siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Añado la nueva imagen al repo y **borro la vieja**
2. Hago modificaciones en mi código para sustituir una imagen vieja por la nueva
3. Compruebo. Todo va perfecto
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "mensajito de turno"
6. git pull [branch]
7. git push [branch]
8. Vuelvo al navegador y las imágenes están rotas
9. Inspecciono y resulta que la imagen a la que llama el src es la vieja

Encontramos

```
<img class="logo" src="./assets/images/tkalogo.png" alt="logo">
```

en lugar de:

```
<img class="logo" src="./assets/images/tkalogo.svg" alt="logo">
```

10. Le pido a **mi compañero** que se coja mi código y compruebe si le pasa lo mismo. Él **lo ve perfecto, con la nueva imagen**.
11. **Me cargo el repo y me lo vuelvo a traer limpio. Ahí va todo de nuevo**.
12. Vuelvo a hacer cambios y a hacer pull y otra vez aparece la llamada antigua. Es como si recuperase algún archivo de caché o algo.

No creo que sea relevante dado el comportamiento, pero en el template.hbs tengo este código

```
<img class="logo" src="{{logo}}" alt="logo">
```

Y en el componente éste:

```
logo: computed('logo', function() {
        return htmlSafe('./assets/images/' + ((config.APP.logo) ? config.APP.logo : 'tkalogo.svg'));
    })
```

¿Os ha pasado alguna vez, tenéis idea de cómo evitarlo?

Comment: ¿Será la caché de Git o la del navegador? Has probado a recargar pulsandoCtrl+F5 (o bien Cmd+R en un mac)?

Comment: @DanielAbril Es el caché del navegador, si estás realizando aún pruebas del desarrollo del proyecto, trata de hacerlo en una pestaña de incógnito o ***la forma más rápida de borrar la memoria caché de un sitio web específico en Chrome es:*** `Ctrl + Mayúsculas + I`. Esto hará que se abra la Herramienta de Desarrolladores. Cuando se muestre la consola de desarrollo tendremos que hacer clic con el botón derecho del ratón sobre el icono Recargar página (refrescar) situado a la izquierda de la barra de direcciones URL.

Comment: Esto hará que se muestre un menú desplegable con tres opciones de entre la cuales deberemos elegir la que dice: Vaciar la caché y volver a cargar de manera forzada. En el momento en el que hagas clic en dicha opción dicho botón, la página se refrescará y ya se mostrará la versión más actualizada y no la versión que se encontraba almacenada en la caché @DanielAbril

Comment: gracias por las sugerencias a ambos, conozco las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome. Por supuesto he limpiado no sólo la caché sino todo el local storage.
Por cierto, con F12 se abre la misma herramienta. Y si accedes a la pestaña Application tienes todo lo que el navegador ha almacenado de tu aplicación.
Así que no es un problema de caché de navegador. Sucede al recompilarse la app tras hacer un pull en git